# Magento emails not working error log 403

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cpanel, customer-emails

All emails in my Magento 1.9.2.4 shop: invoice , new registration , contact us ECT. do not work. I receive error log 403. 
I haven't made any changes on the site. Can the reason be in the cPanel?

Comment: You should consider provide more information, what does your log say? What is your email setup? What is your server setup? What have you tried to resolve the issue / how have you investigated?

Comment: The site working from 2 years and never made such mistakes. I resive error log: File not found [/home/designcorner/public_html/403.shtml]

Comment: Do you have SMTP configured?

Answer (score 0):

You should contact your host, I had a similar issue when the host changed their SMTP policy.